# Dynamic component size on page

Tags: html, css, adjustment

I am making a webpage that auto adjusts so I can use it for any device. I have fixed almost everything so it size adjusts properly except my categories, its the .hip div. They only line underneath each other when the web size is small, but I want the actually Buttons/images to become smaller and follow my other divs. I have no clue why this won't work.

The images will not change size only move. I want them to stay the same place. Only move upwards and become smaller, but look at

```css
.hip {
  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
  
}
.hip:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.hip:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
.hip:hover button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
.hip img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(10px);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;

  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 200px;

}
.hip button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: .3em 1em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.83em;
}
```

```html
<div class='hip'>
  <a href="barnevakt.html"><img src='http://www.izoncam.com/files/2015/03/babysitter.jpg'width="150" height="150"  />
  
  <button>Barnevakt</button></a>
</div>

<div class='hip'>
  <img src='http://eltying.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Czym-najlepiej-malowa%C4%87-%C5%9Bciany.jpg' width="150" height="150"/>
  <a href="maling.html"><button>Maling</button></a>
</div>

<div class='hip'>
  <a href="renovering.html"><img src='http://www.michanikos.gr/uploads/92f19f6fa1ae850d5be16672b4688868.jpg'width="150" height="150" />
  <button>Oppusing</button></a>
</div>
<div class='hip'>
  <a href="hagearbeid.html"><img src='https://img0.etsystatic.com/020/1/6791412/il_fullxfull.482239814_qief.jpg'width="150" height="150" />
  <button>Hagearbeid</button></a>
</div>

<div class='hip'>
  <a href="hundegåing.html"><img src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Q069CqhGSxE/VIwYNYTnddI/AAAAAAAABdY/7bWjxwD5k8g/s1600/dog-walker.jpg' width="150" height="150"/>
  <button>Dyrepass</button></a>
</div>

<div class='hip'>
  <a href="skolehjelp.html"><img src='https://adhdteacher.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/school_sleeper.jpg'width="150" height="150" />
  <button>Skolehjelp</button></a>
</div>

<div class='hip'>
  <a href="dugnader.html"><img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/EVS_volunteer_project_within_Nevitsky_Castle_reconstruction.jpg' width="150" height="150"/>
  <button>Dugnader</button></a>
</div>

<div class='hip'>
  <a href="måking.html"><img src='http://www.activehealthinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/snowIQ_-_winter_street_shovelling60471.jpg' width="150" height="150"/>
  <button>Måking</button></a>
```

Comment: How about a proper title for your question?

Comment: it works for me, www.hånd.no?

Comment: oh you probably cant write the Å try to click the link.

Comment: I clicked the link. Maybe that kind of characters in a link only works with a Norwegian language setting?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/?useragent=Validator.nu%2FLV+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xn--hnd-ula.no%2F

Comment: Yea, maybe its a norwegian domain, i will reedit with some pictures:)!

Comment: try this link instead! (http://www.xn--hnd-ula.no/) :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few observations:

1. **Image sizes (5000px X 5000px)** - images are too big to be shown over the web. Sizes should be optimized further with a scope getting load down by 70 to 80%.
2. **Positions of HIP divs** - why these divs are appearing at the top. Best practice would be to wrap all these HIP divs in another div and place it exactly above the FOOTER div.
3. **Transition of image position** is happening very smooth and let it be that way only. I recommend not to play around size of images for different screen sizes rather let the images fall one below other - this is the best possible look-n-feel you can expect for those many images. OR else you will need to display the images in SLIDER format for smaller screen sizes - again this would be little time consuming.

Comment: This seems to be a bunch of criticisms of the site that are unrelated to the question that was actually asked.

Comment: @Quentin It's absolutely integral to the question that was asked. The HTML is structured in a way that won't support what the OP wants to achieve. You could provide a more "direct" answer that fakes the desired behavior, but that wouldn't solve the underlying problem. It would, however, waste huge amounts of OP's time in the future.

Comment: @Quentin - Its not criticism at all but the observations - apologies if taken personally. Question was to assist Janthan in getting the web page responsive specifically about the IMAGE display part. I have given my recommendations for the same - so I dont see its unrelated to the post.

Comment: Dude, dont worry this feedback is great! this is the first webpage ive ever build so i need it! :D am trying so hard to fix stuff but i am learning everything i do when i do it, so what whould take you 10min wil maybe take me an hour. if you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your HTML is completely out of order, and the images aren't set to resize fluidly. In fact, it's likely impossible to achieve more desirable gallery behavior without rewriting your HTML.

The reason your images appear the way the do is because they're not wrapped in any container that's interacting manageably with the other elements present on the page. In particular, your `#front-page` has an `absolute` position that's giving the visual illusion that that it's at the top of the document. It's that same rule that's forcing the images to ignore the `#front-page`. Unsetting it will make your design "break," but it's a necessary first step toward achieving what you want.

Here's a working example of what (I assume) you're going after. I suspect more complex media queries would yield a better result, but this is a starting point for a more maintainable document:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjmmYB

Note that

```
<div class="mock-image"></div>
```

Represents an `<img>` tag that I was too lazy to add, but the behavior should remain the same for any 1:1 dimensioned image. As an added benefit, setting the `padding` of the `<img>` instead of the `height` will allow you to maintain consistent aspect ratios for images that aren't 1:1.

**edit**

The rationale

Positioning

Keep it simple. By default elements are `static`-ly positioned in the document, and most layout elements are `display: block`, meaning they stack on top of one another. This is good. Converting them to `relative` has very few drawbacks, and often enhances default behavior (enabling `z-index`ing, among other things). If you notice, of the four elements that are direct children of `<body>` (`<header>`, `.splash`, `.gallery`, and `<footer>`), they're all either `static` or `relative`. You don't have to keep those class names, but I recommend keeping almost *all* elements either `static` or `relative`, with very few, specific exceptions. Certainly you should keep layout containers `static` or `relative`. Using `position: absolute` or `fixed` takes them out of the flow of the document, and this has very unintuitive consequences.

Containers

You'll also notice that where there's content (the `.guts` and `.mock-image` elements), that content is wrapped in containers (`.splash` and `.gallery`, respectively). Those containers are there to decrease complexity. Instead of having eight images butting up against the `.splash`, we only have one `.gallery`. It's far more manageable to deal with two interacting elements than nine, and this is a simple case. Complexity will only grow from here. Additionally, they're both set to `width: 100%`, meaning as long as they're positioned `relative` or `static`, they'll always stack on top of each other, which is exactly the kind of predictable behavior you want.

The gallery

An added benefit of setting the containers to `width: 100%` is that it scales with the window, meaning all percentage-based children (in this case your images) will scale with the window too. Typically you do want it to max out at some point (hence the `.wrap` with a `max-width: 1000px`), but up until that point, especially for galleries, this is the behavior you want. The `@media` query is a bonus: since 12.5% of a mobile screen is tiny (on an iPhone it would be only 40px by 40px), on smaller screen dimensions the media query sets images to 25% instead of 12.5%, resulting in an 80px by 80px image.

Since your thumbnails will only ever be at most 162.5px by 162.5px in this case, you also, as another poster said, want to crop them in an image editing program before you use them, otherwise you're wasting crazy bandwidth.

Comment: can you help me with that? if i send you my html document will you be able to add the one you made with my design and pictures? and get my html document cleaned up. i do not know what that is out of order other then what you just said. anyhow this is my first webpage and am new to html so i whould be very glad if you can help me out! :D.

Comment: I annotated the code a little bit and I'll beef up my answer, but I can't add the pictures and design for you, sorry. The CodePen snippet I sent you is pretty bulletproof. I'll explain it a little better in an edit above, but it's almost shippable as-is. You really just have to drop your elements in and do some styling. How are you gonna learn if you don't work it out yourself? :P

Comment: True stroy, i was talking more about order in the html document. i assume u went on the webpage and looket at the entire code, or do think that the codes i added here was compleatly out of order? anyhow thanks mate!:D

Comment: @JonathanStigar The code in the link was out of order, haha. In general (read: _almost all_ cases), the order of code in the document should correspond 1:1 to the way the elements appear on the page. If the header is the first thing you see on the page, it should be the first piece of code inside `<body>`. That's how browsers render the elements by default (hierarchically, so to speak), and you really don't want to fight it; you'll end up spending a lot of time producing something very fragile. I edited the answer above with a little more info.

Comment: @JonathanStigar Oops, I made edits to the CodePen and forgot to update the link (the wrap was missing before). Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so mutch! you have really been a great source of information!